# understanding promise chaining with catch and then

Tags: javascript, promise

I am unable to understand the result of the below promise chain

```
function job(state) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (state) {
            resolve('success');
        } else {
            reject('error');
        }
    });
}

let promise = job(true);

promise

.then(function(data) {              ///1
    console.log(data);

    return job(true);
})

.then(function(data) {              ///2
    if (data !== 'victory') {
        throw 'Defeat';
    }

    return job(true);
})

.then(function(data) {              ///3
    console.log(data);
})

.catch(function(error) {              ///4
    console.log(error);

    return job(false);
})

.then(function(data) {              ///5
    console.log(data);

    return job(true);
})

.catch(function(error) {              ///6
    console.log(error);

    return 'Error caught';
})

.then(function(data) {              ///7
    console.log(data);

    return new Error('test');
})

.then(function(data) {              ///8
    console.log('Success:', data.message);
})

.catch(function(data) {              ///9
    console.log('Error:', data.message);
});
```

The output is

success
Defeat
error
Error caught
Success: test

I can see why 'success' and 'Defeat' are printed.
But then I am confused. Why 3, 4,5 are skipped and it executes 6?
Then since 7 throws an error, shouldn't 9 be executed instead of 8?

Comment: `Why 3, 4,5 are skipped` because you reject (throw an error) in 2? `return new Error('test');` does not reject the promise returned in 7 - you could `return Promise.reject('test')` or `throw 'test'` (like you did in 2)

Comment: or, more simply - `.then` returns a Promise. If you return a Promise from `.then`, the `Promise` returned by `.then` is (for all intents) the `Promise` you return. If you return ANY other value, `.then` returns a fulfilled/resolved (whatever term you use) `Promise` of that value. If you `throw` inside `.then` it returns a rejected `Promise` with that value as the reason

Comment: thanks, but I'm still confused. Since error is thrown in 2, shouldn't 4 be run?

Comment: what makes you say it isn't? How can you tell the difference between 3 and 4 (by the way, 3,4,5 are NOT skipped either, I forgot to mention that) - 1,2,4,6,7,8 are all executed

Comment: it's simple. a rejection will skip any "then" until there's a "catch" (it's really more complex than that, since a `then` can ALSO handle rejections, but your code doesn't have any "then" that does so) ... so, a rejection from a "then" (or "catch") is a rejected promise or a `throw`n error ... returning a `new Error` is NOT a rejection

Comment: Got it. Thank you.  Can you please show an example of then handling a rejection?

Comment: `.then(onFullfilled, onRejected)` ... the second function passed to .then would handle a rejection ... in fact `.catch(fn)` is really `.then(null, fn)` anyway

Comment: note, according to docs lets say you did, `.then(a, b)` and neither a nor b is a function, internally, the will be treated like `.then((x) => x, (x) => { throw x; })` - you don't need to know this though :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the promises returned by the `then` and `catch` methods by the numbers you have put in comments next to them. Note that these `then` and `catch` methods execute synchronously, so we immediately have a bunch of promises, and they are all pending at first. The only one that is immediately fulfilled is `promise` (which didn't get a number, so let's give it number 0).

Now let's look at this step by step:

Promise 0 (`promise`) gets assigned a promise that fulfilled with value "success".

Callback 1 executes, because promise 0 fulfilled, and so we get output "success". This callback returns a new promise that also fulfils with value "success". Promise 1 copies the state of that promise, and so it fulfils with "success".

Callback 2 executes too, because promise 1 fulfilled. You don't print anything in the callback number 2, but if you would, it would have been output. The `if` condition is true, and so callback 2 throws an error "Defeat". This makes that promise 2 rejects with "Defeat" as reason.

> Why 3, 4,5 are skipped

The third callback is skipped, because that one is only supposed to execute when promise 2 fulfils. But as it rejected, and you didn't provide a catch callback for it (second argument of `then` is absent), promise 3 just copies the state of promise 2. So now promise 3 is rejected too.

Callback number 4 is not skipped; it executes! Promise number 3 gets rejected, and it is there that "Defeat" is printed. This callback then proceeds to return a rejected promise (`job(false)`) having reason "error" (see `job`), and so promise 4 also rejects with the same reason.

Callback 5 is only supposed to execute when promise 4 fulfils, but as promise 4 rejected, it does not execute. Here also there is no callback to execute when promise 4 rejects, so promise 5 just copies the state of promise 4 and rejects with reason "error".

> and it executes 6?

Callback 6 executes, because it is supposed to execute when promise 5 rejects -- which it did -- and so we get an output "error". This callback returns a string "Error caught", which becomes the value with which promise 6 fulfils.

Callback 7 executes, because it is supposed to execute when promise 6 fulfils -- which it did -- and so we get an output "Error caught". Callback 7 returns an `Error` object with message "test". Promise 7 fulfils with this Error object as value.

> Then since 7 throws an error, shouldn't 9 be executed instead of 8?

That is a misunderstanding. Callback 7 does *not* throw an error. It returns an object, which happens to be an instance of `Error`, but that is irrelevant. If a `then` callback returns a value that is not a promise object (or another "thenable"), then that value will be what the corresponding promise fulfils with. `Error` objects are no exception to that rule.

So callback 8 executes, because it is supposed to execute when promise 7 fulfils -- which it did -- and so we get an output "Error caught". Nothing is returned here, which means promise 8 fulfils with the value `undefined`.

Callback 9 does not execute, because it is supposed to execute when promise 8 rejects, but it fulfilled. As there is no handler for when promise 8 fulfilled, promise 9 just copies the state of promise 8. As there is no callback attached to promise 9, nothing more gets executed.

I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have one curious question.
Why are we having two ways to handle a promise rejection? - passing a second argument to then and using catch?
Is there any advantage of using one over the other?

Comment: The difference is tiny. If you want to handle both fulfilment and rejection of a promise, then using both arguments is the "purest", but it is common to first have the `then` with one argument, and then chain a `catch`. The difference is that the rejection will be taken over by the promise that `then` had returned, and on which `catch` is called. So there is one more promise at play like that. The "advantage" is that if there is an error in the `then` callback, it will result in a rejected promise on which you have the `catch`, so you would catch such error too. Not so with the 2-arguments.

Comment: Can you please provide an example if you don't mind?

Comment: That would need a lot of text. The comments area is not really suitable for followup questions. If you can formulate this as a more concrete question, then you could consider posting it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

While the [trincot explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77534931/3309466) is very well detailed, what helped me to undestand the promise chain, is to visualize it.

Here is what is happening in your code example:

- every promise has a success or a failure
- the dotted path represents the failure
- the solid path represents the success
- the colored path represents the code example execution

Nice to mention:

- if the dashed paths are not handled by a catch, it generates an `unhandled promise exception` that leads to a nodejs process crash
- if a promise returns a promise (or a promise chain), it is inserted into the oriented graph that is being created

[image: promise chain]